# Imports in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

im extremely new to node js.

When you use an import statement in node js, what is the search algorithm like?
So here the person is importing React from 'react'
Does it first look in the node_modules folder always?
What if i had an alternative folder in the same level as node_modules containing react module?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You know that they are in the folder because you need to install them with NPM before using them.

Comment: Okay but if i have another folder containing react module external to node_modules, which module will it use?

Comment: There is no point in that,  you should not have the files elsewhere because you always install them with NPM. For your own scripts that you want to have in other files, then yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Anyways if you are asking specifically about React, you should read some guide about how to install it.

Comment: @Eloi i assume react in this case is just an example. The question is more along the lines of, how does the import know whether to look in node modules vs a local file... and that's a relatively easy to research question.

Answer (score 0):

The resolving algorithm is described in the book Node.js Design Pattern [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781783287314/1/ch01lvl1sec11/the-module-system-and-its-patterns).

> The resolving algorithm can be divided into the following three major
> branches:
>
> File modules: If moduleName starts with "/" it's considered
> already an absolute path to the module and it's returned as it is. If
> it starts with "./", then moduleName is considered a relative path,
> which is calculated starting from the requiring module.
>
> Core modules: If moduleName is not prefixed with "/" or "./", the
> algorithm will first try to search within the core Node.js modules.
>
> Package modules: If no core module is found matching moduleName, then
> the search continues by looking for a matching module into the first
> node_modules directory that is found navigating up in the directory
> structure starting from the requiring module. The algorithm continues
> to search for a match by looking into the next node_modules directory
> up in the directory tree, until it reaches the root of the filesystem.